# Having a property which can be any object that adheres to a specific protocol

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building an app in Swift, and I have a a view controller which I am going to use in 2 places to display very similar screens but with some minor differences.

I have a protocol called myProtocol, and I've a view controller with a property called viewModel which adheres to this protocol. The viewModel can be an instance of aViewModel or bViewModel, but they both have the same methods from the protocol, but return different values depending on where the view controller is used.

Now, in objective-c I can do

`@property (nonatomic, strong) id <myProtocol>viewModel`

and then can set it as `viewModel = [aViewmodel new]` or `viewModel = [bViewmodel new]`. How can I achieve something similar in swift?

I've tried adding the property as `let viewModel: myProtocol? = nil`, but this is giving an error saying it can't infer a type. Just wondinerg if you guys could give me some advice. I'm new enough to swift, but have been using Objective-c for a few years

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Swift 3:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    //...
}

var viewModel:MyProtocol?

class ViewModel: MyProtocol {
    //...
}    

viewModel = ViewModel()
```

Comment: You are welcome. At SO we thank by upvoting and accepting the answer.

Comment: I tried to accept it at the time but it said I needed to wait, and I'd to rush off and get my hair cut!  Just accepted it there. Thanks! Also, follow up question, is it possible to state that anything that adheres to that protocol, must have a delegate which implements a function (or adheres to a second protocol) or am I thinking about this wrong?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but sounds like a new topic to me. You better ask a new question, show your code, describe what you want to achieve with this code and what problem you are running to.